# Laplace Domain Transfer Function for Feedforward System

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, laplace-transform, block-diagram

I am trying to obtain the overall transfer function of this feed-forward system which consists of an oscillating input being mixed with a local oscillator to create a mixed signal as the output. G1 and G2 represents the transfer functions for some filters, amplifiers, etc.

My question is, considering that the transfer function for some component is given by the output/input signals \$\frac{OUT(s)}{IN(s)}\$, how is this represented for the mixer, and therefore for the overall system? Is it correct for me to break up the overall system into 3 parts such as

$$\frac{U_{g1}}{U_i}\left(\frac{U_m}{U_{g1} + U_{lo}}\right)\frac{U_o}{U_m} = G_1T_1G_2$$

Where \$T_1\$ is the mixer's transfer function? I think my confusion may be coming from a misunderstanding of block-diagram algebra... any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frduX7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: T1 cannot be defined that way: If you include signal Ulo in your transfer function you will end up with Uo=G1G2Ui + G2Ulo. (By the way, the title is misleading: a feedforward system takes its own input in two branches with different transfer functions before adding them together. There is no such a thing here, as the local oscillator is independent on the input).

Comment: There is nothing like an "overall transfer function". A transfer function can relate the output signal to one single input only. What you can do is the followig: Write down the output signal as a function of two (or more) input signals.

Comment: Learn how to convolve in the Laplace domain.